# Undo "Don't show again" for Windows Defender prompt in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

While using Idea, it pops up 'Windows Defender might be impacting your build performance.
I click "Don't show again" & "Don't show again for this project" by mistake. I tried a lot of ways, but not work. How can I undo this operation?
[image]

Comment: You may unexclude them in "Windows Defender" settings in your OS.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005028939-Slow-startup-on-Windows-splash-screen-appears-in-more-than-20-seconds

Answer (score 1):

Seems it can only be resetted manually, in my case:

> %USERPROFILE%\.PhpStorm2019.2\config\options\other.xml

Set it to false

```
<property name="ignore.virus.scanning.warn.message" value="false" />
```